# Add file in every directory form foreach

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I am trying to add one xlsx file to zip directory and folders for each locale from an existing database with the given name.

This part is working.

I have trouble figuring out how to in every of that created folders add the same JSON file that I defined in my code.

Can anybody help with that?

This is my working code.

```
$rootDir = $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir();
    $dir = $rootDir . '/../web/files/';
    $file = $dir . 'my_file.xlsx';
    $getFile = basename($file);

    $findLocale = $this->getLocalRepository()->findAll();

    $jsonFileToAdd = $dir . 'jsonFile.json';

    $zip = new \ZipArchive();
    $zipName  = $rootDir . '/../web/my-files/zip/' . 'dictionary.zip';

    $zip->open($zipName, \ZipArchive::CREATE);
        $zip->addFile($file, $getFile);

    if ($zip->addEmptyDir('app')) {
        foreach ($findLocale as $locale) {
            $zip->addEmptyDir($locale->getLocale());

        }
    }

    $zip->close();
```

Comment: Well call `addFile` after you created the new empty directory, what is the problem with that?

Comment: Every addEmptyDir($locale->getLocale()) folder needs to have that json file. Don't know how to put it in each of them. @04FS

Comment: By doing it directly after you _created_ them? That happens in the inner foreach loop, via the line `$zip->addEmptyDir(…);` - so, add a line directly after that, that adds the file to that folder?

Comment: I tried that way it does not create anything. @04FS